# Регулярное выражение для определения гос.номера

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Регулярное выражение для выделения цифр из госномера автомобиля:

```
Regex(@"^\w?(\d{3})(\w{2}(\d{2,3})?)?")
```

Срабатывает на разные комбинации цифра и букв/регионаб но на вариант только трех цифр не срабатывает. Например, `а123аа123`, `а123`, `123аа` - сработает. `123` - нет.

### Почему?

Не знаю, что это было, но после перезагрузки студии тоже заработало. Спасибо всем, за ответы. Вопрос снят.

Comment: Кстати: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регистрационные_знаки_транспортных_средств_в_России#.D0.94.D0.B5.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D1.83.D1.8E.D1.89.D0.B8.D0.B5

Comment: Странно, вроде бы всё корректно, и на regex101 и даже на regexstorm всё отрабатывает.

Comment: Даже в шарпе работает: http://rextester.com/RGOAK13156

Answer (score 1):

Протестировал на http://rextester.com/TVHRC55846 отрабатывает корректно.
Можете добавить больше контекста?